# Swap an array element and shift the rest of the elements

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = ['100', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

var newIndex = 6;    // index where we want to swap the element
var oldIndex = 0;    // index from where we swapped the element
var replaceBy = arr[oldIndex];

if (newIndex < oldIndex) {
    for (var i = newIndex; i <= oldIndex; i++) {
        var saveCurrent = arr[i];
        arr[i] = replaceBy;
        replaceBy = saveCurrent;
    }
} else if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
    for (var i = newIndex; i >= oldIndex; i--) {
        var saveCurrent = arr[i];
        arr[i] = replaceBy;
        replaceBy = saveCurrent;
    }
}
console.log(arr); // logs out ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "100"]
```

Is there a JavaScript method or a better solution to swap an array element and shift the rest of the elements?

I am looking for a better solution, possibly by just using 1 loop. So far I came up with the above solution. `if` and `else if` have same code except in the `for block`. After swapping, the array will either shift to the right or to the left based on the index.

Comment: [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the array twice. Once to remove the item at `oldIndex`, and once to insert it at `newIndex-1` (because removing it will do the shift in the first place).

Comment: `arr.push(arr.shift())` ? - oh, I just read the input and current output - didn't realise it wasn't that simple :p

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - you're wrong about newIndex-1 by the way

Answer (score 2):

You could take [`Array#copyWithin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin) and move the parts for making place for the swapping an element.

```js
const
    move = (array, from, to) => {
        const value = array[from];

        if (from < to) array.copyWithin(from, from + 1, to + 1);
        else array.copyWithin(to + 1, to, from + 1);
        array[to] = value;
        return array;
    };

console.log(...move(['100', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 0, 6));
console.log(...move(['100', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 6, 0));
```

Comment: wow - never seen that method, and it's not exactly very new!  doesn't work if your oldIndex > newIndex though

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when we swap the index, i.e `newIndex=0` and `oldIndex=6`. The expected result should be `array=['F', '100', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']` . They array will have to shift either to the left or to the right based on the index.

Answer (score 1):

splice a splice works

```js
var arr = ['100', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
var newIndex = 6;    // index where we want to swap the element
var oldIndex = 0;
arr.splice(newIndex, 0, arr.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0])
console.log(arr);
```

Just showing it works if oldIndex > newIndex as well

```js
var arr = ['100', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
var newIndex = 1;    // index where we want to swap the element
var oldIndex = 5;
arr.splice(newIndex, 0, arr.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0])
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [Array Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)...

```js
function arrMove( arr, oldIndex, newIndex )
  {
  let [temp] = arr.splice(oldIndex,1)
  arr.splice(newIndex,0, temp)
  }

const myArray = ['100', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

arrMove(myArray,0,6 )

 console.log( JSON.stringify(myArray))
```

> you can also use a wrapper

```js
// -------------  wrapper: 
Array.prototype.arrMove = function(oldIndex, newIndex)
  {
  if ( Number.isInteger(oldIndex) && Number.isInteger(newIndex) 
    && this.length > Math.max( oldIndex, newIndex)
    && oldIndex >=0 && newIndex >= 0 &&  oldIndex != newIndex )
    {
    let [temp] = this.splice(oldIndex,1)
    this.splice(newIndex,0,temp)
    }
  else throw 'Index(s) value(s) is invalid';
  return this
  }
// ----------- end wrapper


const myArray = ['100', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']


console.log( JSON.stringify( myArray.arrMove(0,6) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I presume you mean to *move* an element within the array.

A function for that with range check, and using a double [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```js
const arr = ['100', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
console.log(`original array =>`, String(arr));

console.log(`0, 6 =>`, String(move(arr, 0, 6)));
console.log(`2, 1 =>`, String(move(arr, 2, 1)));
console.log(`5, 2 =>`, String(move(arr, 5, 2)));
console.log(`7, 1 =>`, String(move(arr, 7, 1)));

function move(arr, from = 0, to = 0) {
  // throw error if one of the indexes falls
  // outside the array
  if ([from, to].find(v => v > arr.length - 1)) {
    throw new RangeError(`one of the swap values (${
      from}, ${to}) is not within range`);
  }
  
  // create a clone of the original array
  // because this function will mutate it
  const arrClone = [...arr];
  
  // splice twice
  arrClone.splice(to, -1, arrClone.splice(from, 1));
  return arrClone;
}
```